# Common Lisp: Recursive "is-equal" function - results are incorrect

Tags: recursion, lisp, equals

I'm having trouble developing a recursive function that will see if two list's are equal to each other, including looking at the sub list's. So far I have:

```
(defun are-equal2 (X Y)
(cond
    ((null X) nil)
    ((and (listp (first X)) (listp (first Y)))
        (are-equal2 (first X) (first Y))
    )
    ((eq (first X) (first Y))
        T                   
    )
)
)
```

It seems to work sometimes. for example `(are-equal2 '((A) B) '((A) B))` returns T and `(are-equal2 '((A) B) '(A B))` returns nil. but `(are-equal2 '(F (A G) B) '(F (T G) B))` returns T..... I think it might have to do with my last conditional. I'm not sure how to re-work it though.

Never mind lol. Did some tinkering waiting for a reply and got it. Did a bunch of nested if statements. Code:

```
(defun are-equal2 (X Y)
    (if (and (listp (first X)) (listp (first Y)))
        (are-equal2 (first X) (first Y))
        (if (and (eq (first X) (first Y)))
            (if (and (endp (rest X)) (endp (rest Y)))
                T
                (are-equal2 (rest X) (rest Y))
            )
            nil
        )
    )
```

)

Comment: I got it. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Your rewrite doesn't actually work. Try running `(are-equal2 '((a) b) '((a) c))`.

Comment: Please invest a few minutes in [learning how to format Lisp code](http://dept-info.labri.u-bordeaux.fr/~idurand/enseignement/PFS/Common/Strandh-Tutorial/indentation.html)

Comment: Listp checks for proper list. You should use consp. If it is then its (and (eq... (car X) (car Y)) (eq... (cdr X) (cdr Y)). For everything else it's (eql X Y)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can get away with a tail-recursive version here.

I am afraid you will have to think of your arguments as **trees**, not **sequences**.

E.g.,

```
(defun are-equal (x y &key (test #'eql))
  (or (funcall test x y) 
      (and (consp x)
           (consp y)
           (are-equal (car x) (car y))
           (are-equal (cdr x) (cdr y)))))
```

This compares leaves using [`eql`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_eql.htm) by default (cf. [Rules about Test Functions](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/17_b.htm)), as opposed to [`eq`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_eq.htm) in your example:

```
(are-equal '((1) a) '((1) a))
==> T
(are-equal '((1) a) '((1) b))
==> NIL
(are-equal '((1) a) '((2) a))
==> NIL
(are-equal '(("1") a) '(("1") a))
==> NIL
```

Comment: The OP used `eq` rather than `eql`, so it makes sense that this answer does as well.  However, for the sake of future readers, note that `eq` is stricter than `eql.  E.g., with this definition in SBCL,`(are-equal (1+ most-positive-fixnum) (1+ most-positive-fixnum))` returns `NIL`.

Comment: Huh. How about that. I guess in my midnight programming mind set I only tested the begging of the lists. This seems to make a lot more sense. Didn't know about consp either. Interesting. This may help with my subset function as well. Thank you sds. Have a good one!

Comment: @user2326106 If you need a subset predicate, you should consider Common Lisp's [`subsetp`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_subset.htm).